# localhost not accesible to load flask app via docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask

I have a flask-mongodb project  where I use `docker-compose` to create a container of my flask app with mongodb data as backup . Now I can load my app perfectly in my linux vm browser with typing `localhost:5000` but in windows 10 I get that my connection is refused when typing the same thing in chrome .

My docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb 
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
    volumes:
    - ./mongodb/data:/data/db 
  flask-service:
    build:
      context: ./flask 
    restart: always 
    container_name: flask 
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment: 
      - "MONGO_HOSTNAME=mongodb"
```

My DockerFile :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER user <user@gmailcom>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y bcrypt  
RUN pip3 install Flask-PyMongo py-bcrypt
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/templates
COPY webservice.py /app/webservice.py
ADD templates /app/templates 
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3" , "-u" , "webservice.py" ]
```

How I connect to mongodb with my flask app :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongodb_hostname = os.environ.get("MONGO_HOSTNAME","localhost")
client = MongoClient('mongodb://'+mongodb_hostname+':27017/')
db = client['MovieFlixDB']

 #more code ... 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I would appreciate your help with this . Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox or the Docker Desktop application?

Comment: @DavidMaze Docker Desktop